# Simple Fading Divs with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have:

```
    var t_out;
    var idx = 0;

    function cycleReviews() {
        clearTimeout(t_out);
        t_out = setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(idx)
            $('#review_' + idx).animate({opacity: '0'}, function () {
                $('#review_' + idx).addClass('hide');

                $('#review_'+ (idx+1)).css('opacity', '0.0').removeClass('hide').animate({opacity: '1.0'});
                idx++;
            });
            if(idx == 2) {
                console.log('reload')
                idx = -1;
            }
            cycleReviews();
        }, 2000);
    }
```

To cycle through three divs, fading them one to the other.

I am having trouble getting it to work properly, concerning when it restarts (goes back to the first slide, idx 0).

How can I get this to work properly?

---

Fiddle:

```js
'use strict';

var obj = [{'id': 0, 'review': 'Test1', 'author': 'Bob1'},{'id': 1, 'review': 'Test2', 'author': 'Bob2'},{'id': 2, 'review': 'Test3', 'author': 'Bob3'}];

$(function () {
            var html = '';
            var first = true;
            $.each(obj, function (i, v) {        
                html += '<div id="review_' + i + '" class="review ' + (first ? '' : 'hide') + '">';
                html += '<p>' + v.review + '</p>';
                html += '<p class="small">' + v.author + '</p>';
                html += '</div>';
                first = false;
            })
            $('#review_container').html(html);
            cycleReviews();

    var t_out;
    var idx = 0;

    function cycleReviews() {
        clearTimeout(t_out);
        t_out = setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(idx)
            $('#review_' + idx).animate({opacity: '0'}, function () {
                $('#review_' + idx).addClass('hide');

                $('#review_'+ (idx+1)).css('opacity', '0.0').removeClass('hide').animate({opacity: '1.0'});
                idx++;
                if(idx == 2) {
                    console.log('reload')
                    idx = 0;
                }
                cycleReviews();
            });


        }, 2000);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container text-center home-2">
                    <h1 class="hero">Customer Reviews</h1>
                    <div class="bullets"><span id="bullet_1">&#8226;</span> <span id="bullet_2">&#9702;</span> <span id="bullet_3">&#9702;</span></div>
                    <div id="review_container">
                    </div>
                    <p class="green">A happy client</p>
                </div>
```

Comment: By making a JSFiddle or all your code so we can test it and help you ;)

Comment: That is a rather silly way to animate something as simple as a single property. I would suggest you remove all of this, make a single CSS keyframe animation for opacity and run it with `transition-delay` by adding classes to the elements.

Comment: setting it to -1 makes no sense

Comment: @epascarello I was messing with it as the idx wouldn't go back to 0 for some reason.

Comment: You update the id inside of the finish callback and check to see if it is two outside of it...

Comment: And when you go to the end, your code does not know that it needs to hide the last item that was shown. You need to change the logic for how it hides and shows. If you have HTML markup, it would help.

Comment: I have added a fiddle in my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You're overcomplicating things a bit there. I've made slight modifications to your code - added the index as a cycle parameter, changed it so that you don't have to look for previous element to hide it, but hide all the elements and show only the indexed one, removed hard-coded number of elements, etc. Here it is:

```js
'use strict';

var obj = [{'id': 0, 'review': 'Test1', 'author': 'Bob1'},{'id': 1, 'review': 'Test2', 'author': 'Bob2'},{'id': 2, 'review': 'Test3', 'author': 'Bob3'}];

$(function () {
            var html = '';
            var first = true;
            $.each(obj, function (i, v) {        
                html += '<div id="review_' + i + '" class="review ' + (first ? '' : 'hide') + '">';
                html += '<p>' + v.review + '</p>';
                html += '<p class="small">' + v.author + '</p>';
                html += '</div>';
                first = false;
            })
            $('#review_container').html(html);
            cycleReviews(0);

    var t_out;

    function cycleReviews(idx) {
        clearTimeout(t_out);
        t_out = setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(idx)
            if(idx == obj.length) {
                    console.log('reload')
                    idx = 0;
            }
            $('.review').animate({opacity: '0'}, function () {
                $('.review').addClass('hide');
                $('#review_'+ (idx)).css('opacity', '0.0').removeClass('hide').animate({opacity: '1.0'});                
                cycleReviews(idx+1);
            });


        }, 2000);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container text-center home-2">
                    <h1 class="hero">Customer Reviews</h1>
                    <div class="bullets"><span id="bullet_1">&#8226;</span> <span id="bullet_2">&#9702;</span> <span id="bullet_3">&#9702;</span></div>
                    <div id="review_container">
                    </div>
                    <p class="green">A happy client</p>
                </div>
```

Note, this can be improved even further, of course, but this will get you started.

---

How I'd write the `cycleReviews` function:

```js
'use strict';

var obj = [{'id': 0, 'review': 'Test1', 'author': 'Bob1'},{'id': 1, 'review': 'Test2', 'author': 'Bob2'},{'id': 2, 'review': 'Test3', 'author': 'Bob3'}];

$(function () {
            var html = '';
            var first = true;
            $.each(obj, function (i, v) {        
                html += '<div id="review_' + i + '" class="review ' + (first ? '' : 'hide') + '">';
                html += '<p>' + v.review + '</p>';
                html += '<p class="small">' + v.author + '</p>';
                html += '</div>';
                first = false;
            })
            $('#review_container').html(html);
            cycleReviews(0);

    function cycleReviews(idx) {
            $('.review').addClass('hide');
            setTimeout(function(){
              $('#review_'+ idx).removeClass('hide');
              setTimeout(function(){
                  cycleReviews((idx+1) % obj.length);
              }, 1500);
            }, 500);

    }
});
```

```css
.review {opacity: 1; transition: opacity 0.5s linear}
.hide {opacity: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container text-center home-2">
                    <h1 class="hero">Customer Reviews</h1>
                    <div class="bullets"><span id="bullet_1">&#8226;</span> <span id="bullet_2">&#9702;</span> <span id="bullet_3">&#9702;</span></div>
                    <div id="review_container">
                    </div>
                    <p class="green">A happy client</p>
                </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I like it clean, without **useless IDs** and stuff,
with **clickable** (and automatically generated) **bullets**
and even with a **pause on hover**:

```js
var obj = [{'id': 0, 'review': 'Test1', 'author': 'Bob1'},{'id': 1, 'review': 'Test2', 'author': 'Bob2'},{'id': 2, 'review': 'Test3', 'author': 'Bob3'}];

$(function () {

  var $reviewsContainer = $('#review_container'),
      $bulletsContainer = $('.bullets'),
      idx = 0,
      slides = "",
      bullets = "",
      itv;

  $.each(obj, function (i, v) {        
    slides  += '<div><p>'+ v.review +'</p><p class="small">'+ v.author +'</p></div>';
    bullets += '<span></span>';
  });

  $reviewsContainer.append(slides);
  $bulletsContainer.append(bullets);

  slides  = $reviewsContainer.find("> div");
  bullets = $bulletsContainer.find("> span").on("click", function(){
              idx = $(this).index();
              showSlideIdx();
            });

  function showSlideIdx() {
    slides.removeClass("active").eq(idx).addClass("active");
    bullets.removeClass("active").eq(idx).addClass("active");
    idx = ++idx % obj.length;
  }

  function play() { itv = setInterval(showSlideIdx, 2000);}
  function stop() { clearInterval( itv ); }

  $(".container").hover(stop, play);
  showSlideIdx(); // the first ones
  play();         // START!

});
```

```css
#review_container{
  position:relative;
  height:100px;
}
#review_container > div{
  position:absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity:0;
  transition: 0.8s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.8s;
}
#review_container > div.active{
  visibility: visible;
  opacity:1;
}
.bullets span{ font-size:50px; cursor:pointer; }
.bullets span.active:after{content: "•";}
.bullets span:after       {content: "◦";}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container text-center home-2">
  <div class="bullets"></div>
  <div id="review_container"></div>
  <p class="green">Hover to pause!</p>
</div>
```